# the method function(Patient) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments () anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I currently have a function being checked every so often by an event block. However, I keep receiving the error 'the method function(Patient) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments ()' when I try to run the simulation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method requires an argument `myPatient` of type `Patient`, you must provide that if you call the method.

So you cannot call `function()`. You MUST call `function(somePatient)` where `somePatient` is an agent of type `Patient`. It is your responsibility to provide that.

If you call the function from a flow-chart block and it should be used for some `Patient` flowing through the block, you *may* use `function(agent)`, but only if this key-word `agent` is available and if the `agent` flowing through is of type `Patient`.

Check the fundamentals of functions in the help, this is crucial in getting functions to work for you :)